# Xamarin - How to show Routes using Google Maps API

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I want to show the route between two positions in my app. I have a Google Maps API but I do not know how to get the Information from Google. I have read, that I need to call a link from Google and then I become Code in json. But how I can code that? Can you please help me with any codes...

Answer (score 1):

1.you need to implement POLYLINE which connected sequence of line segments created as a single object. You can create straight line segments, arc segments, or a combination of the two

2.when you call google api you would get points using which you need to draw the polyline(Path) on you map

3.you need to customrender your map somewhat same in the below code

```
 [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace MyAndroid.Droid
{
public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer
{
    List<Position> routeCoordinates;

    public CustomMapRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribe
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
            routeCoordinates = formsMap.RouteCoordinates;
            Control.GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMapReady(Android.Gms.Maps.GoogleMap map)
    {
        base.OnMapReady(map);

        var polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
        polylineOptions.InvokeColor(0x66FF0000);

        foreach (var position in routeCoordinates)
        {
            polylineOptions.Add(new LatLng(position.Latitude, position.Longitude));
        }

        NativeMap.AddPolyline(polylineOptions);
    }
}
```

}

follow [this](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/CustomRenderers/Map/Polyline/Droid) sample for reference

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I do not have that experience to do that alone :(

Comment: then there are people call developer's you need to hire them and then they might help you..

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are using Xamarin.Forms.Maps, and you have everything setup, Here is an example, to move a Map, or set a pin:

```
  Maps.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
                              new Position(-23.4859591, -47.4420192),
                              Distance.FromMiles(0.5)));


            var pin = new Pin
            {
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = new Position(-23.4859591, -47.4420192),
                Label = "Maps",
                Address = "www.abc.com",
            };

            Maps.Pins.Add(pin);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but that was not my question,.